Clangd auto-inserts C++ headers instead of C headers
The header insertion for clangd imports C++ style headers as opposed to C style headers when editing *.c files.
For Example: ctime as opposed to time.h
Is there any way to disable this?
Nvim Lspconfig setup:
["clangd"] = function()
    local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
    lspconfig.clangd.setup {
        cmd = { "clangd", 
            "--background-index", 
            "--completion-style=detailed", 
            "--header-insertion=iwyu", 
            "--log=verbose" 
        },
        filetypes = { "c" },
        root_dir = function()
          return vim.loop.cwd()
        end,
    }
end,



What do you mean by "imports"? Auto-inserts them when completing functions from them?

Yeah, the auto-insert

I can reproduce in VSCode. I suggest reporting a bug to Clangd.
